# Recursive closure, nested closures

Tags: php

With the following array:

```
$values = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'];
```

I would like to iterate this array and build the code below:

```
$q->method('string1', function($q)
{
    $q->method('string2', function($q)
    {
        $q->method('string3', function($q)
        {
            $q->method();
        });
    });
});
```

How can this be done in PHP?

Comment: Is this some kind of interview test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$values = ['string1','string2','string3'];
$callback = function($q) use (&$values,&$callback) {
    if( !$values) $q->method();
    else $q->method(array_shift($values),$callback);
};
$callback($q);
```

This should suit your needs :)

Comment: This is pretty neat Mr. Niet. I have learned a lot just from looking to your answer.